# How to join the same table twice?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am stuck on creating a SQL query. I have the following two tables:

```
member
(
 memberid    int,
 membername  varchar(50)
)

message
(
 messageid   int, 
 message     varchar(100), 
 sender      int, 
 receiver    int
)
```

`sender` and `receiver` are foreign keys with table `member` and column `memberid`. I want to display list of messages with `name` and `id` of `sender` and `receiver`.

How can I establish proper joins here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like

```
SELECT  *
FROM    message m INNER JOIN
        member snd ON   m.sender = snd.memberid INNER JOIN
        member rcv ON   m.receiver = rcv.memberid
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in this case because your `message.sender` and `message.receiver` allow `NULL` values. You probably do not want to skip messages if either of these columns is `NULL`:

```
select msg.messageid as messageid,
       msg.message as message,
       mem1.memberid as sender_id,
       mem1.membername as sender_name,
       mem2.memberid as receiver_id,
       mem2.membername as receiver_name
from message as msg
left outer join member as mem1 on msg.sender = mem1.memberid
left outer join member as mem2 on msg.receiver = mem2.memberid;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ac80e/2/0